# Views with Qtip - load only view content

Tags: views, ajax

I was looking around for a solution of my problem without luck, unfortunatelly I stuck :/

The problem is as follows:

I have created a view to show list of custom type nodes and another view with Contextual filters to show single selections. On the table view each position have a linked tooltip (qtip), all I want to do is to show in tooltip only content of the view not the whole page. I dont really know how to achieve this as a result I'm getting whole page displayed in tooltip (with header/footer/menus etc.)